# Comparar palavras de um texto com uma lista de Enum's

Tags: java

Tenho um Enum que contém uma lista de valores. Tenho um método onde recebo um texto como parâmetro. Este método além de percorrer Enum, quebra o texto por palavras. A função principal do método é ver se existe alguma palavra do texto que seja igual a algum valor do Enum. O código está abaixo:

```
public String checkTipo(String texto) {
        List<TipoPokemon> lista = Arrays.asList(TipoPokemon.values());
        String palavras[] = texto.split(" ");

        for(int i=0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++){
        for (String palavra : palavras){
            String tipo = lista.get(i).getNome();
                if (palavra.toLowerCase().equals(tipo)){
                    return "Olá";
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Meu Enum é:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

public enum TipoPokemon {

    FIRE("FIRE"),
    WATER("WATER"),
    GRASS("GRASS"),
    ELECTRIC("ELECTRIC"),
    ICE("ICE"),
    DARK("DARK"),
    GHOST("GHOST"),
    FAIRY("FAIRY"),
    PSYCHIC("PSYCHIC"),
    DRAGON("DRAGON"),
    POISON("POISON"),
    GROUND("GROUND"),
    ROCK("ROCK"),
    NORMAL("NORMAL"),
    BUG("BUG"),
    FIGHTING("FIGHTING"),
    STEEL("STEEL"),
    FLYING("FLYING");

    private String nome;

    private TipoPokemon(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Estou tentando debugar e na parte onde eu crio a variável *tipo*, ele retorna no `foreach` e não faz a verificação do `if`, eu preciso comparar palavra com Enum, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida. O código não está funcionando? Se não estiver, o que dá errado? Quais são so tipos de pokémons que você tem no seu enum? Se o código não funciona, poderia dar um exemplo de texto no qual ele não funciona, mas deveria funcionar?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Você poderia juntar o conteúdo de sua lista de valores em uma string, tipo: "valor1;valor2;valor3;valor4;valor5" e depois perguntar em um loop se a stringvalores.contains(palavra)

Comment: Pergunta editada @VictorStafusa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não precisa definir o nome desse jeito porque todo enum tem um método `name()` que faz exatamente o que o seu `getNome()` faz.

Além disso, todo enum tem um método `valueOf(String)` que faz uma parte do que o seu `checkTipo(String)` faz.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

import java.util.Locale;

public enum TipoPokemon {
    FIRE, WATER, GRASS, ELECTRIC, ICE, DARK, GHOST, FAIRY, PSYCHIC,
    DRAGON, POISON, GROUND, ROCK, NORMAL, BUG, FIGHTING, STEEL, FLYING;

    public static String checkTipo(String texto) {
        String palavras[] = texto.split(" ");
        for (String palavra : palavras) {
            try {
                TipoPokemon tipo = valueOf(palavra.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
                return "Olá";
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Ignora a exceção e continua no for.
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Só não entendo porque o método retorna `"Olá"` ou `""` ao invés de retornar `boolean` ou o `TipoPokemon` encontrado.

Eis aqui um teste para ele:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TipoPokemon.checkTipo("ROCK"));
    System.out.println(TipoPokemon.checkTipo("bug"));
    System.out.println(TipoPokemon.checkTipo("banana"));
    System.out.println(TipoPokemon.checkTipo("banana cereja acerola"));
    System.out.println(TipoPokemon.checkTipo("banana cereja dark acerola"));
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Olá
Olá


Olá
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/vSM69o)

Comment: Obrigado, eu consegui de uma outra forma também...Vou postar em outra pergunta que farei.

Comment: O que o Locale.ROOT faz ?

Comment: @Douglas Faz com que o seu código não dê pau se estiver sendo executado na Turquia - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase - Isso ocorre porque as regras de maiúsculas e minúsculas são diferentes na Turquia. Assim sendo, usar o `toLowerCase()` e o `toUpperCase()` sem parâmetros é algo considerado como uma má prática de programação por algumas pessoas. Algumas ferramentas que analisam código automaticamente, como por exemplo o FindBugs, também apontam isso como uma possível causa de problemas. A solução é colocar o `Locale.ROOT`.

Comment: Entendi...Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção sem precisar capturar exceção:

```
public boolean checkTipo(String texto) {
    List<String> palavras = Arrays.asList(texto.toUpperCase().split(" "));

    for (TipoPokemon tipoPokemon : TipoPokemon.values()) {
        if (palavras.indexOf(tipoPokemon.name()) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Conforme esclarecido na resposta do @Victor Stafusa você não precisa atribuir uma string a cada item do Enum se a string for igual ao nome do próprio item; a função `name()` já extrai esta string pra você.

Teste:

```
@Test
public void checkTipo() {
    assertTrue(checkTipo("não dark outro"));
    assertFalse(checkTipo("não darkness outro"));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu não sei se vai me atender....eu fiz outra pergunta agora detalhando mais o meu objetivo final.