# Validar texto antes de ir pra tela

Tags: java, jsf

Tenho o seguinte `dataTable`:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="tabela" var="c" value="#{geracaomb.lista}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                    rendered="#{not empty geracaomb.lista}" paginatorPosition="top">
                    <p:column styleClass="botoesGrid">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{geracaomb.editar(c.id)}" process="@this" update="cadastro,pesquisa"
                            ajax="false" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{geracaomb.excluir(c)}" ajax="true" process="@this" update="pesquisa">
                            <p:confirm header="#{msg['cabecalho.apagar.registro']}" message="#{msg['apagar.registro']}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="exploud" hideEffect="fade">
                            <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                        </p:confirmDialog>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['nome']}" sortBy="#{c.nome}" style="width:12%;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.nome}" escape="false" />
                    </p:column>
```

E tenho o seguinte método:

```
public String checkTipo(String texto) {
        List<TipoPokemon> lista = Arrays.asList(TipoPokemon.values());
        String palavras[] = texto.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            String tipo = lista.get(i).getNome().toLowerCase();
            for (String palavra : palavras) {
                if (palavra.toLowerCase().equals(tipo)) {
                    texto = texto.replace(palavra, "<b>"+palavra+"</b>");
                }
            }
        }

        return texto;
    }
```

Meu método que faz a pesquisa:

```
public void pesquisar() {
        try {
            lista = dao.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

O objetivo é que ao carregar o texto no `dataTable` faça-se uma verificação para que caso haja alguma palavra no texto, a palavra seja formatada, como no exemplo ficará em negrito. O que preciso é que toda vez que o botão pesquisar for acionado, antes dos dados irem pro `dataTable`, sejam validados antes, ou seja, como chamo o meu método no `outputText` ?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165762/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa não sou muito experiente ainda no site..Isso tem problema ?

Comment: Não, nenhum problema. A ideia é orientar quem for responder a pergunta ou então analisá-la sob algum outro aspecto saber onde olhar por mais informações.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema parece estar em um rumo estranho, se entendi direito o que precisa, essa resposta resolve.

- Isso **não precisa de algoritmos** pois o jsf já tem uma propriedade para tratar isso.
- Outra coisa vai precisar salvar a formatação, pois se recuperar o dado do banco de dados, não será mostrada em segundo momento.
- A propriedade é: **escape="false"**

Veja um exemplo

```
<p:outputLabel value="Valor <br /> <srtong>description<strong/>" 
               styleClass="sys-font-normal" escape="false"  />
```

Atualize para o teu contexto.

Comment: Nâo entendi a parte do value, só lembrando que algumas palavras que serão formatadas apenas...

Comment: O value é uma propriedade, nesse caso do **outputLabel**, mas depende no que tiver usando, é o valor do campo, 
em jsf costuma ser assim por exemplo, **value=#{seu_bean_manage.nome}**

Comment: Deu certo? marca o resposta que resolveu ter problema, para ajudar outras pessoas

Answer (score 1):

no seu outputText você pode definir uma variável com o texto já formatado...

la no seu bean você cria uma String textoFormatado.

utiliza a mesma lógica do método checkTipo pro valor da String

depois no outputText value="#{seuBean.textoFormatado}

caso não resolva, espero ter dado uma luz rsrs

Comment: Como seria o código de percorrer minha lista ?

Comment: for (TipoPokemon tipo: lista) {
        system.out.println(tipo.values());
    }

isso?