# JSF + RichFaces - Imprimir HTML em DataTable

Tags: jsf, rich-faces

Pessoal tenho um código HTML no banco e preciso mostrar ele em um DataTable. Porém ao imprimir ao invês de redenizar o HTML o navegador está mostrando o HTML. Como faço para redenizar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a propriedade:
* **escape="false"**

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165766/validar-texto-antes-de-ir-pra-tela/165790#165790)