# Verificar e editar um List

Tags: java, jpa

Eu possuo um List:

```
private List<Geracao> lista;
```

Essa lista vai ser preenchida com dados vindos de um database:

```
lista = dao.findAll();
```

O método `findAll()` :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Geracao> findAll() throws Exception {
        log.info("Encontrando todas as Gerações");
        return em.createQuery("from Geracao").getResultList();
    }
```

Estes dados após serem preenchidos na `lista` irão para a tela (JSF). Eu gostaria de fazer uma formatação no texto antes de ir pra tela, exemplo: Possuo um atributo chamado `nome` na classe `Geracao`. Como posso fazer para pegar o valor que virá do banco, editar e aí sim jogar para a `lista` ?

Meu objetivo final é que no texto que virá do banco antes de ir para a tela, faça se uma verificação se existe uma palavra x. Caso exista x no texto, x será formatado, exemplo como em negrito antes de ir para a tela. Ex:

```
texto = texto.replace(palavra, "<b>"+palavra+"</b>");
```

Comment: Que tipo de formatação? Você está querendo aplicar alguma regra de negócio (por exemplo, colocar o sobrenome da frente do nome)? Ou você está querendo fazer alguma coisa puramente cosmética (por exemplo, limitar a quandidade de caracteres). A resposta é importante pois define qual o melhor componente (classe de negócios, managed bean, etc) é mais apropriado para a manipulação

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly editei a pergunta com a informação.

Comment: Cara, particularmente me parece que o que você quer fazer deve ser feito na view, então eu faria no JSF direto: `<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace('palavra', ')', '<b>palavra</b>')}" />`

Comment: @Sorack o problema é que não é a mesma palavra, e dependendo da palavra vai receber diferente formatação, no meu caso aí eu vou fazer uma verificação juntamente com uma lista vinda de Enum.

Comment: Ah entendi @Douglas. O melhor me parece ser fazer no bean, mas acho que a resposta do Giovane deve cair como uma luva pra você

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165766/132 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165762/132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso:

```
final String palavraChave = "palavra";
final String trocaPalavraChave = "<b>palavra</b>";

List<Geracao> lista = dao.findAll().stream().forEach(geracao -> {
  if(geracao.getNome().contains(palavraChave)) {
    geracao.setNome(geracao.getNome().replaceAll(palavra, trocaPalavraChave));
  }
});
```

Para acessar variáveis externas ao `.stream().forEach()` elas devem ser imutáveis, `final`.

---

### UPDATE

O código acima foi feito baseado na API do Java8, caso esteja usando uma versão inferior você pode usar o `foreach` básico:

```
final String palavraChave = "palavra";
final String trocaPalavraChave = "<b>palavra</b>";

List<Geracao> lista = dao.findAll();
for(Geracao geracao : lista) {
  if(geracao.getNome().contains(palavraChave)) {
    geracao.setNome(geracao.getNome().replaceAll(palavra, trocaPalavraChave));
  }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Como falei no comentário, você pode tratar várias regras dentro do mesmo for, exemplo:

```
List<Geracao> lista = dao.findAll();
for(Geracao geracao : lista) {
  regraDeNome(geracao);
  regraXYZ(geracao);
}

private void regraDeNome(Geracao geracao) {
  final String palavraChave = "palavra";
  final String trocaPalavraChave = "<b>palavra</b>";

  if(geracao.getNome().contains(palavraChave)) {
    geracao.setNome(geracao.getNome().replaceAll(palavra, trocaPalavraChave));
  }
}
private void regraXYZ(Geracao geracao) {
  // tratamento da regra
}
```

Comment: .stream().forEach são métodos do List ?

Comment: Sim, faz parte da API do Java8

Comment: Giovane, vou te incomodar de novo...Eu não possuo só o atributo nome para verificar, tem outros, terei de fazer um for para cada atributo ?

Comment: Não, deixe dentro do mesmo `for`. Pense que dentro do `for` estão todas as instruções que devem ser executadas para cada elemento da lista, então você pode por todas as validações necessárias para cada elemento dentro do mesmo `for`. Talvez uma boa prática para não ficar um código muito denso e cheio de regra de negócio você pode criar métodos de validação de regra onde trata cada regra num método separado. Vou exemplificar isso.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o rowStyleClass do dataTable e criar um método para formatar ou tratar as palavras.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{ManagedBeam.lista}" var="item"
rowStyleClass="#{ManagedBean.tratarPalavra(item)}"
```

e no método:

```
public String tratarPalavra(Geracao g) {
    // lógica e tratamento...
    return String;
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, só estou achando estranho é que a formatação não está indo pra tela, mas no debug vi que está fazendo tudo que eu quero.

Comment: você pode criar no css do projeto uma formatação padrão...

exemplo:
no CSS
.vermelho {
background-color:red;
}
e retornar no método do beam a String "vermelho";
entendeu?

Comment: Este atributo do dataTable espera retorno de uma classe css ?

Comment: Exato! Qualquer coisa na documentação do primefaces tem bem explicadinho. Conseguiu aí?

Comment: Não porque ele formata tudo, e eu quero formatação apenas em palavras específicas :/

Comment: já tentou ao invés de usar o <b> usar o <strong>??

Comment: A solução do Giovani atendeu, mesmo assim obrigado.